# Film: 70s, basement, female, frozen man... or something

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

This is either a movie or television production, can't remember which. The likely production date is sometime in the 1970s. My memory is very brief; time has probably distorted it.

In a suspense sequence, a girl or woman runs down a flight of stairs into what might be a basement. The basement looks completely unnatural, maybe it's covered in frost? Maybe limestone? The basement might be impossibly deep, like it connects to some supernatural domain? Maybe not. The female sees a creepy man who seems to be frozen mid-stride, but she's still in a hurry as if the man will soon become a threat.

Comment: What about this (other than the supernatural ambience) makes this sci-fi or fantasy?

Comment: Maybe my edit improves things.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[*The Sixth Sense*](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0702166/) (1972 TV series)? Episode: "Once Upon a Chilling".

I think this may be the one. Here is the plot summary from [IMDb](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0702166/):

> A woman working at a foundation researching cryogenics sees frozen visions of her dead boss.

This episode is available in 4 parts on YouTube, here is the 1st part. You can see a creepy man frozen in mid stride in a lower floor cryogenic room near the beginning of the video.

Comment: If this isn't it, I don't know what is. That frozen guy looks just like the one I remember.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't seen the movie, so can't positively identify the scene mentioned, but this might be *Chill*, which was produced in 2007 but might well have looked older due to budget constraints.  The film is loosly based on H.P. Lovecraft's short story, "Cool Air" but strays from the original plot.

> Muñoz lives in the back of a deli which he runs, and the protagonist Sam (Thomas Calabro), a writer who comes to work at the deli for survival money, gets dragged into the web of killings. Sam also falls in love with a woman named Maria (Ashley Laurence) who runs a clothing stores across the street and is being threatened by a local cop, Detective Defazio (James Russo), whom she dated once.

Maria is the probable basement runner, and the cold and ice are significant to the plot.

Comment: Thanks for the input. I neglected to say I'm old and I saw this when I was a kid. Definitely made in the 70s or so.

Comment: @MackTuesday I was afraid of that, but it seemed like a possible candidate.

Comment: I also grew up in the 70s and I've seen a ton of these films, but I need more plot details. Can you remember anything else about the story?

Comment: @theguest - Sorry, I got nothing.